# How can I access data in R without mutating the environment

Tags: r, dataframe

When I open a package, say `ggplot2`, dataset like `diamonds` are defined in my environment.

Is there a way to access the diamonds dataset **without** mutating my environment ?
like

```
a <- ggplot2.data("diamonds")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
ggplot2::diamonds
```

See `?"::"` for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Use `data` and specify the `package`:

```
data(diamonds,package="ggplot2")
head(diamonds)
  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48

sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: well here diamonds is a name that got attached to your namespace. for some interactive session that is better. but if you want your code to be reusable, you want every assumption made explicit. here head(diamonds) assumes you have diamonds in your namespace, and nothing guarantees that statically. so if you reorder the 2 lines, the same code wont work and you wont get any warning

Comment: @nicolas No `diamonds` becomes a variable in your global environment. The other difference between this method and the `::` one is that you don't load `ggplot2` and its dependencies via a names space. I suppose I might have misunderstood what you meant by mutating your envrionment. But I agree that `::` might be safer to use, especially if there are possibilities of other objects named `diamonds`.

Comment: hi, yes having some new global variable is what I meant by mutating my 'environment'. different idioms are more natural depending where you come from. in my specific case I access R from another langage, using the F# type provider, so I prefer to not rely on anything in the 'environment' which does not 'environnate' me much in that setup